# Get sql query result without using join

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've below tables players, matches.

```
player_id | group_id
 -----------+----------
 20       |   2
 30       |   1
 40       |   3
 45       |   1
 50       |   2
 65       |   1

match_id | first_player | second_player | first_score | second_score
 ----------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------------
 1       |    30        |       45      |      10     |     12
 2       |    20        |       50      |      5      |     5
 13      |    65        |       45      |      10     |     10
 5       |    30        |       65      |      3      |     15
 42      |    45        |       65      |      8      |     4
```

Desired result:

```
group_id | winner_id
 ----------+-----------
   1     |  45
   2     |  20
   3     |  40
```

Below are cases:

1. In group 1 the winner is player 45 with the total score of 30 points.
2. In group 2 both players scored 5 points, but player 20 has lower ID and is a
   winner.
3. In group 3 there is only one player, and although she didn't play any matches, she is a winner.

I have written below query with **left join** & it satisfies all the 3 cases. But I need query **without any join**.

Below is query for reference:

```
select group_id,player_id,totalScores from
 (select group_id,player_id,sum((
  case when player_id = first_player then first_score
   when player_id = second_player then second_score
   end
)) as totalScores

from players p
left join matches m on (p.player_id = m.first_player or p.player_id = m.second_player)

group by group_id,player_id
order by group_id,totalScores desc,player_id ) as temp
group by group_id
order by group_id,totalScores desc,player_id
```

Comment: First select the distinct groups from the `players` table and then use a correlated subquery to get the player with the highest score in each group.

Comment: @Sachin can you please help me with query.

Comment: "I need query without any join." Why that? Does the query ou have work correctly and produce the intended result?

Comment: @JonasMetzler with left join it produce the desired result. I am looking for query without left join for other purpose.

Comment: The question is why? Which advantage do you expect? What is wrong with using JOIN? Most people here have a real issue to solve, yours here doesn't sound like one, unless you can explain why to urgently get rid of JOIN which already procudes a correct result. What should be used instead of JOIN and why?

Comment: The query may happen to produce a correct result. But that is in no way guaranteed. The result is not deterministic. In fact, your query is even invalid according to the SQL standard, and you can only run it in MySQL, because you are working in cheat mode. Don't ever do that. Always `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in MySQL. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is invalid. In the main query you group by group_id only, but select a player_id and totalScores. Which player_id? Which totalScores? There can be many per group_id. MySQL should raise an error here, and if it doesn't this indicaes that you are working in MySQL's notorious cheat mode that silently applies the `ANY_VALUE` function on such columns. Don't do that. You get arbitrarily chosen values that can even stem from different rows. In MySQL, always

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

in order not to be allowed to write invalid queries.

Apart from that, you have an `ORDER BY` clause in a subquery. A subquery cannot be ordered, and in fact, some DBMS would raise an error here. Subquery results are unordered sets of data by definition.

If run in MySQL cheat mode, your query selects one row per group_id, each which an arbitrarily chosen player_id and and arbitrarily chosen total score. This is not what you want.

Here is a query that solves the task properly. It joins the tables as in your query, but then ranks the players by group_id with `ROW_NUMBER`. At last it shows the highest ranked player per group.

```
with scores as
(
  select
    p.group_id,
    p.player_id,
    coalesce(sum(case when player_id = first_player then first_score else second_score end), 0) as score
  from players p
  left join matches m on p.player_id in (m.first_player, m.second_player)
  group by p.group_id, p.player_id
)
, ranked as
(
  select group_id, player_id,
    row_number() 
      over(partition by group_id order by score desc, player_id) as rn
  from scores
)
select group_id, player_id
from ranked
where rn = 1
order by group_id;
```

(You could rank right away, but I thought it more readable to build the sums first and then rank in a separate step.)

As you say you don't want to join (which seems a very weird request) and you only need the players' total scores from the matches table, you can replace the outer join by a subquery in the players' select clause:

```
with scores as
(
  select
    group_id,
    player_id,
    (
      select coalesce(sum(case when player_id = first_player then first_score else second_score end), 0)
      from matches m
      where p.player_id in (m.first_player, m.second_player)
    ) as score
  from players p
)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/PxP_gMXI